# Vue best practice, props object or primitive types?

Tags: vue.js

Vue support both primitive types and object as props to pass them from parent to its child.

I ever heared that it is a best practice to always pass primitive types instead of passing an Object. Maybe it is because the primitive types are easy to detect if changed.

Is it true? Is it a best practice or just something dumb?

Comment: Generally the issue with passing objects or arrays as properties has to do with the fact that the properties of objects and the elements of arrays can be **mutated** inside the child component without having to *emit* the changes. That makes it difficult in some cases to reason about *what* is making changes to an object as the complexity of your application grows. I suspect that is where you have heard that the best practice is to pass primitive values (which would *force* you to emit to make changes).

Comment: That said, it's still very valuable to be able to pass objects an arrays to children, you just need to be careful when/if you are going to be modifying those objects. A better stated "best practice" might be that it's best practice to pass primitive values if your intention is to modify the value. Personally I ignore that best practice regularly. Many of my applications do not appear to rise to the level where I have a hard time understanding where things are happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no real "best practice" at it really depends on what you're trying to accomplish.
You can use both really, but remember when passing non-primitives you're passing a **POINTER**, not the actual object. Thus, when modifying said object inside the child, you will also modify the original object.

If you're going to pass around objects, that you want to MODIFY, but as a "copy", you can always pass them using the expand operator to create a copy as such.

```
{ ...myObject }
[ ...myArray ]

<child-object :someprop="{...object}"></child-object>
```

That way you ensure that if you're going to modify the object at child level, the child owns a copy of this object and you're not getting unexpected behavior on the parent.

Comment: Take note that the spread syntax (...) does _not_ deep copy a whole object, it only goes one level deep and shallow copies any nested objects